# How can I ctreate a simple makefile for minGW + gfortran

Tags: makefile, gfortran

I am absolutely new in gfortran+minGW. 
I need to create makefile.
When I run

```
$ gfortran  -c q.f
```

All is ok!
But how can I run makefile like this?

```
CC = gfortran 
q.o :  q.f 
        $(CC) -c q2.o q2.f
```

I receive error  “CC: command not found”.

(OS – Win 7 (64))
Tanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

It kind of looks like you're trying to run the makefile as a regular script.  Try

```
 $ make
```

or

```
 $ make -f mymakefilename
```

if you named the file something other than "makefile" or "Makefile".

You *can* potentially just execute the makefile, but if so you need a "shebang" line, something like

```
 #!/usr/bin/make
```

at the top of the file, but frankly hardly anyone uses that option.  Just use the *make(1)* command.

**Update**

It's because they're in the wrong order.  Makefiles process (by default) the first target in the file.  When you run make it sees the rule to make, `q.o` from `q.f`, it compiles it, and says, "Okay, I'm done."

If you put the `q.exe` target first, it says "Hmmm, I want to build q.exe and to do that I need a q.o.  Do I have a q.o?  No?  Okay, hen I'll build a q.o.  I have a rule for that -- I can build a q.o from q.f.  okay, that's done.  Now can I build q.exe?  Oh, yes, I can.  I'll build q.exe.  Anything?  Nope, I'm done."

If you were to use the commend

```
  $ make q.exe
```

then you'd explicitly tell make to make q.exe, which would cause the same thing to happen, but better you should reorder your makefile and get used to the way they work.

Comment: If that did the trick, click the check mark next to this answer; that gives me bonus points for the "accepted" answer.